# How to get two windows with different plots

Tags: r, window, plot

When we have a window with plots, is there a way to tell R to display a new plot in a new window?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create a new one:

```
plot(1:10)
x11()            # This has aliases on different OSes
plot(10:1)
```

Answer (score 46):

```
plot(1:1)
dev.new()
plot(2,2)
dev.set(dev.prev()) # go back to first
title(main="test dev 1")

dev.set(dev.next()) # go to second
title(main="test dev 2")
```

Comment: This seems preferable to accepted answer because platform independent.

Answer (score 21):

You might actually want to partition the window  instead so you can have mutuple plots in the same window if you are comparing them:

The following will create 3 horizontal partitions:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,1))
```

So with 3 plots it will look like the following in a single Window:
[image]