# Render R plot_ly in new tab by default

Tags: r, render, plotly

Is there a way to render an R plotly chart in a new tab by default rather than in the Rstudio viewer pane?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`plot(1:1)
dev.new()
plot(2,2)
dev.set(dev.prev()) # go back to first
title(main="test dev 1")`

`dev.set(dev.next()) # go to second
title(main="test dev 2")`

I think your question has been answered here: [How to get two windows with different plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916129/how-to-get-two-windows-with-different-plots)

Comment: Thanks @cgage but what I am asking about is the plotly library, https://plot.ly/r/, not standard R plots

Comment: You could use `plotly_POST()` but that'll open the plot in a browser by default.